# legend label being truncated

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm trying to create a legend that will contain the color of the line it corresponds to and the label. My current code is plotting the legend but is only plotting the first letter of the label (D instead of DL11). I'm wondering how I can get my plot to stop truncating the label. I'd like to be able to add more lines and corresponding colors/labels in the future. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab


data = loadtxt("/home/***")
d, tno1, qno1 = data[:,1], data[:,2], data[:,3]                         
d, tno1, qno1 = loadtxt("/home/***", usecols = (1,2,3), unpack=True)


plt.plot(tno1, qno1, label='DL11')
plt.legend( ('DL11') )
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you have used `label` you don't need to call legend with arguements

Comment: Did you just re-post this question?

Comment: thanks! Guess I over-thought that one.

Answer (score 3):

You have hit an interesting un-packing issue.

Either

```
 plt.legend()
```

or

```
 plt.legend(('DL11',)) # <- note the comma
```

will get the desired result.

To understand why it does this, see the code at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L422

calling `plt.legend(('DL11'))` in equivalent to calling `plt.legend('DL11')` which falls into the `len(args) == 1` case, it then zips your string against the list of lines -> generates the label of 'D' as you only have one line.

Don't think this is a bug, but it is subtle.

Answer (score 1):

I believe pyplot expects a list of legends. For a one-item list, like yours, just

```
pyplot.legend(['DL11'])
```

My guess is that pyplot.legend('DL11') gets the list's first item, that is 'D'.

Hope it helps